# Imaging a bootable CompactFlash Card

Tags: backup

How do I create an image(clone for backup) of a bootable 4GB CompactFlash Card which has Ubuntu 10.04 linux from a Windows 7 system?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a CompactFlash reader (and don't mind shutting down your Ubuntu system), you can pop the card in and grab a copy of [`dd` for Windows](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd).  Can't vouch for it in Windows, but works a treat in *NIX.

Comment: @garvyface: no i have a bootable Ubuntu 10.04 CompactFlash card already..just want to clone it for backup reasons.

Comment: @Iceman: you just need a system to access the raw disk (a reader or the original system booting from another disk). It's an IDE interface.

If you don't want to reboot you could even get away with a temporary read-only mount of the filesystems (mount -o remount,ro / && sync), then run the dd over network - you would still have a 'crashed' system)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that cloning a CF card should be the same as any other IDE drive. In this case you can use a live CD like [PartedMagic](http://partedmagic.com/) which includes the tools you need like [clonezilla](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/free_imaging_software.html) and [DD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix)).

I have personally used DD to make a copy from my compact flash installation to a backup image.

**Backup with DD:**

> dd if=/dev/sda of=/home/user/cf4gb.img

**Restore with DD:**

> dd if=/home/user/cf4gb.img of=/dev/sda

Sorry, but I don't know of any Windows 7 solutions.

Comment: Note that increasing the block size to something more appropriate than the default (e.g. `bs=32M`) will dramatically decrease the amount of time required for `dd` to complete a disk cloning operation.